# Отловить событие изменения свойств компонента React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Для работы с *React.js* использую [ReactDevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi). Там есть возможность из консоли менять значения свойств компонента (довольно сильно облегчает жизнь).

Есть ли какая-то возможность перехватить момент изменения (возможно, вызывается какое-то событие, или что-нибудь в этом роде) и обработать его?

Суть в том, что я хочу отправлять данные на сервер при изменении свойств - но формы как таковой нет, писать ее только для теста не больно-то и хочется, причем когда есть возможность работать с консолью.

Answer (score 1):

Для перехвата запросов в общем случае можно использовать [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), там есть функциональность перехвата запросов, позволяющая создать ответ на месте.

[image: Скриншот приложения Fiddler]

Аналоги: инструменты разработчика в браузере, допустим Chrome.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools: Network]

С помощью этого инструмента можно просмотреть формируемые запросы.

Comment: Не совсем то, что нужно. Мне нужно данные, которые изменились, отправить на сервер, только изменять их я буду через *ReactDevTools*, вот и хочется узнать, возможно ли это?

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать подцепится к  componentDidUpdate
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html